# Drupal Commerce have customer choose how many items to buy

Tags: commerce

I would like to give my customers an option of how many products to buy.
So I would like to have a page (or view) that gives the user the option to but 1, 3, or 6 items of my product each with a little more discount.
For example:
 1 for $3.50
 3 for $7.50
 6 for $10.00

And have those three options displayed next to each other.

Also, I would like to give the customer no other quantities. It is either 1, 3 or 6 items that they can buy.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create 3 separate products in Commerce to represent each quantity. This makes sense especially if you only have a few like you describe. Each "bundle" product can have it's own SKU/model number, and it's own price. This also provides historical record, if you change your bundles in the future, you can keep the old SKU but archive it, and make a new one to represent your new pricing/quantities.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to edit the view commerce cart form and change the select box showing the quantity to contains just 1, 3 and 6.

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if (strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_') === 0 ) {
      //change the select option here
   }
}
```

For the discount option, I think you should change the checkout page and deduct the amount that you want to give concession on and show the user that you're giving this concession based on buying 1 or 3 or 6 products.